# React Native: Update useState instant?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

How can I update a List with `useState` instant? Here is my code I want to update the `userIngredientsList` instant so the user gets the new amount instant on his screen.

```html
function handleItemAmount(id) {
    userIngredientsList.forEach((item) => {
      if (item.id == id) {
        item.amount = item.amount + 1
      }
    })
    firebase.firestore().doc("ingredients/" + user.uid).update({
      ingredients: userIngredientsList
    })
    setUserIngredientsList(userIngredientsList)
  }
```

The database is working, but the local list isn't.

Comment: Is the local list not rendering at all?

Comment: You are directly mutating the react state (by incrementing object values in your array) which is unsupported. Make a new array of new objects with the correct values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead of [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to create a new array, also you can use `...` assignment to copy each items because you cannot mutate the original array from `useState` based on the hooks rule.

I would try as the following:

```
function handleItemAmount(id) {
    const mappedIngredients = userIngredientsList.map(e => ({
       ...e,
       amount: e.id === id ? e.amount + 1 : e.amount
    }));

    firebase.firestore().doc("ingredients/" + user.uid).update({
      ingredients: mappedIngredients 
    })

    setUserIngredientsList(mappedIngredients)
}
```